# Adding a highlight style to EChart Items?

Tags: javascript, css, echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

[In this line echart](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fajbpu?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts) I'd like each symbol (The black dot) to turn white with a blue border when the symbol is hovered over.

This is the configuration for the chart.

```
          data: this.data,
          silent: true,
          sampling: 'average',
          symbolSize: 12,
          symbol: 'circle',
          type: 'line',
          itemStyle: {
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)',
          },
          lineStyle: {
            width: 5,
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
          },
```

The `itemStyle` controls the color of the symbol.  How do we add a hover effect to that?

I thought adding `emphasis` would do it and so I tried both of these configurations:

#### Item Style Nested in Emphasis

```
          emphasis: {
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'white',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          },
```

#### Emphasis Nested in Item Style

```
          itemStyle: {
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)',
            emphasis: {
              color: 'white',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          },
```

But neither has any effect.

Comment: The first version works, [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sagxtu?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts), but was inhibited by `silent: true`, which, in general, means that mouse interaction is to be ignored; funnily enough, this time *I* don't find it listed among the properties of `series:[{type: line, ....}]`, but it's clearly working

Comment: Oh yeah ... I just noticed that as well ... I made the change to the original question Stackblitz ...So I changed it back, forked it, and created an answer with what you are indicating ...

Answer (score 1):

OK ... Figured it out ... The `silent` option was set to `true`.  When that's the case the `tooltip` does not get displayed and the `emphasis` is switched off.

[This is a working demo with the tooltip and the emphasis.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xxsdlx?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts)